# TypeError: unhashable type: 'LineString'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that also conatains spatial info(coordinates).
For some reason although the gemoetry column  has the same info it isn't considered the same, hence the error.

```
FID_buffer  geometry
0   140 LINESTRING (474839.8491500018 4212960.85602500...
1   140 LINESTRING (474839.8491500018 4212960.85602500...
2   140 LINESTRING (474839.8491500018 4212960.85602500...
```

All these are duplicates. I tried: `df.drop_duplicates()` 
and it gives :

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'LineString'
```

Why is this happening and how to perform this correctly?
How to delete rows that are duplicates in a specific column?
Example: Delete according to `FID_buffer` and therefore delete all duplicates in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass by a certain column:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['FID_buffer'],inplace = True)
```

Thus, it is going to remove the others too.